# Java Script function update when new value comes

Tags: javascript, jsp, highcharts

I am currently preparing a project in which I collect data from sensors, save them in an SQL database and display the result using HighCharts on a JSP page. I would like the page to refresh when new data arrives.

My idea is to check the length of the array and redraw the chart when the length changes. However, the page graph only refreshes once after a set time and never again. Could anybody help me?

```js
var length_check_temp = 0;
var length_check = 0;
function multiplelinechartF() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'multiplelinechart',
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      var formatteddata = [];
      for (var key in result) {
        var singleObject = {
          name: '',
          data: []
        }
        singleObject.name = key.toUpperCase();
        for (var i = 0; i < result[key].length; i++) {
          singleObject.data.push([Date.parse(result[key][i].time), result[key][i].value]);
        }
        formatteddata.push(singleObject);
      }
      length_check = formatteddata.length;
      if (length_check_temp != length_check) {
        drawMultipleChart(formatteddata);
      }
      length_check_temp = length_check;
      //drawMultipleChart(formatteddata);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(multiplelinechartF, 50000);
});

function drawMultipleChart(formatteddata) {

  Highcharts.chart('container', {

    title: {
      text: 'Flow Sensors'
    },

    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Sensors values'
      }
    },

    xAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Date'
      },
      type: 'datetime'
    },

    legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    time: {
      useUTC: false
    },

    series: formatteddata,

    responsive: {
      rules: [{
        condition: {
          maxWidth: 500
        },
        chartOptions: {
          legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'center',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? If your AJAX works, then please make a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor and a mock object with the frameworks loaded from CDN

Comment: console.log the two values. Perhaps the new data has the same length as the old

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the console.log doesn't work for me in Intellij

Comment: Why not? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/node-interactive-debugger-console.html

Comment: @mplungjan Because I am using a Community Edition.

Comment: So export as HTML on a server and load in a web browser

Answer (score 0):

Call to [Chart#redraw](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#redraw) event after updating data.
The best method to update is using [Chart#update](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update) that contains redraw.

```
chart.update({
  series: {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
})

chart.redraw();
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pga4ej2v/

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. It would be very useful, but I have got problem how to really check if the data is updated.